Appending innerText on hover and removing in on mouse-out JS
I'm making a nav button that when it is hovered, instead of there just being an icon there, there will also be some text to the right of it. Once the cursor leaves the button, it will go back to just displaying the icon.
HTML
<button title="Style Guide" id="style-guide" hover-text="Style Guide">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-border-top-left"></i>
</button>

JAVASCRIPT
document.querySelectorAll("[hover-text]").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    element.innerText += element.getAttribute("hover-text");
  })
  element.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    element.innerText = element.innerText.replace(element.getAttribute("hover-text"), "")
  })
})


As per reference values in JS two function are totally two different objects. You can try storing action you want to take in a variable and can use as a function to attach at addEventListener or removeEventListener. Please check if below code achieve the result, you wanted.
const a = (element) => {
//add the text
    element.target.innerText = element.target.getAttribute("hover-text");
};

const b = (element) =>{
//remove the text
    element.target.innerText = element.target.innerText.replace(element.target.innerText, "");
}

document.querySelectorAll("[hover-text]").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", a);
 element.addEventListener("mouseout", b);
});


More info: Check out this video on YouTube => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO2b1hU9cfg&list=PLyuRouwmQCjnEupVi5lpP6VrLg-eO-Zcp&index=11

You should give hover-text to i tag. So your html file should be like this:
<button title="Style Guide" id="style-guide">
  <i hover-text="Style Guide" class="fa-solid fa-border-top-left">About</i>
</button>

And the Javascript file:
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("i[hover-text]");

const addHoverText = (element) => {
  const hoverText = element.getAttribute("hover-text");
   element.innerText += hoverText;
 }

const removeHoverText = (element) => {
  const hoverText = element.getAttribute("hover-text");
  element.innerText = element.innerText.replace(hoverText, "")
 }
 
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    addHoverText(button)
  });
   button.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
     removeHoverText(button)
  })
});


This is works for me.
document.querySelectorAll("[hover-text]").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    element.innerText = element.innerText + element.getAttribute("hover-text");
  })
  element.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    element.innerText = element.innerText.replace(element.getAttribute("hover-text"), "")
  })
})

